# Problem loading parallel datasets even after using SubsetRandomSampler

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, pytorch-dataloader

I have two parallel datasets `dataset1` and `dataset2` and following is my code to load them in parallel using `SubsetRandomSampler` where I provide `train_indices` for dataloading.

P.S. Even after setting `num_workers=0` and seeding `np` as well as `torch`, the samples do not get loaded in parallel. Any suggestions are heartily welcome including methods other than `SubsetRandomSampler`.

```
import torch, numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, SubsetRandomSampler

dataset1 = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
dataset2 = torch.tensor([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])

train_indices = list(range(len(dataset1)))
torch.manual_seed(12)
np.random.seed(12)
np.random.shuffle(train_indices)
sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)

dataloader1 = DataLoader(dataset1, batch_size=2, num_workers=0, sampler=sampler)
dataloader2 = DataLoader(dataset2, batch_size=2, num_workers=0, sampler=sampler)

for i, (data1, data2) in enumerate(zip(dataloader1, dataloader2)):
  x = data1
  y = data2
  print(x, y)
```

Output:

```
tensor([5, 1]) tensor([15, 18])
tensor([0, 2]) tensor([14, 12])
tensor([4, 6]) tensor([16, 10])
tensor([8, 9]) tensor([11, 19])
tensor([7, 3]) tensor([17, 13])
```

Expected Output:

```
tensor([5, 1]) tensor([15, 11])
tensor([0, 2]) tensor([10, 12])
tensor([4, 6]) tensor([14, 16])
tensor([8, 9]) tensor([18, 19])
tensor([7, 3]) tensor([17, 13])
```

Comment: You've set the random seeds for `torch`/`numpy`, you will always get the same "random" sampling when you set the same "random" seed of `12`. If you want them to change per program execution, do not set the seeds to something static and let me change/update as they do by default.

Comment: What do you mean by a "parallel data set"?

Comment: See for e.g. two datasets, element at a given index of the datasets differs by prefix 1.

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I am ok with the static thing (I do this for reproducibility of my experiments and also to avoid any future randomness that could hinder parallel dataloading) but I do want the two datasets to get loaded in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using a random sampler, the random indices are expected.
To yield the same (shuffled) indices from both DataLoaders, it is better to create the indices first, and then use a custom sampler:

```
class MySampler(torch.utils.data.sampler.Sampler):
    def __init__(self, indices):
        self.indices = indices
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.indices)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indices)


dataset1 = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
dataset2 = torch.tensor([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])

train_indices = list(range(len(dataset1)))
np.random.seed(12)
np.random.shuffle(train_indices)

sampler = MySampler(train_indices)

dataloader1 = DataLoader(dataset1, batch_size=2, num_workers=0, sampler=sampler)
dataloader2 = DataLoader(dataset2, batch_size=2, num_workers=0, sampler=sampler)

for i, (data1, data2) in enumerate(zip(dataloader1, dataloader2)):
  x = data1
  y = data2
  print(x, y)
```

P.S. got the solution by cross-posting on Pytorch forums but still want to keep it for future readers. Credits to ptrblck.